# The driver server has unexpectedly died! with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

The following code works without any problem when running from Eclipse:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", pathToGeckoDriver);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(2500, 1500));
driver.get(myUrl);
driver.close();
```

But fail when running within a Docker Container with the following error:

```
The driver server has unexpectedly died!
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: 'XXX.X.X.X', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch:'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

I'v read that it might come from incompatibility between the Selenium framewrok and the Firefox version. I'm using the following Selenium Framework:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And Firefox has been newly installed on both environment with the latest version.

I'm running out of ideas ... does anyone have any pointer/ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
The driver server has unexpectedly died!
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- As per the error logs your *Selenium Client* version is **3.13.0** but as per the *Maven* configuration your *Selenium Client* version is **3.14.0**
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_73** which is pretty **ancient**.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is unknown to us.
- Your *Firefox* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u73* , *Selenium Client v3.13.0*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v61.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped. I can now correctly execute it within a Docker container, but it's pretty unstable. I regularly get one of the following error: "The driver server has unexpectedly died!" or "java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:26763". Any hint?

Comment: @hublo I have tried to address your question from the minimal error trace log which you have provided as in _The driver server has unexpectedly died!_. In case you are seeing the error _java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:26763_ can you raise a new question with the error trace log? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.